# Rails API utilizando Gem PUMA Ambiente de desenvolvimento >> Produção

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Desenvolvi um API que conecta em um banco oracle está funcionando corretamente em desenvolvimento, porem quando eu tento executar a GEM Puma em produção, dá erro.
comando para executar

`````
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
! Unable to load application: ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'prod
uction' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit

Erro :
````80:in `validate_secret_key_base': Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' env
ironment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)´´´´

puma.rb
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env
# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }
plugin :tmp_restart
`````

Com isso eu não consigo startar minha aplicação em Produção só em DEV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este erro ocorre quando o sistema não encontra sua definição de `secret_key_base`, que é importante para criptografar cookies, chaves de seção e etc...

Aparentemente há algum problema com suas definições de credenciais. Como mostra o [guia do RoR](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/security.html#custom-credentials), na versão 5.2 é criado o arquivo criptografado `config/credentials.yml.enc` para armazenar informações sensíveis de sua aplicação.

Duas coisas podem estar acontecendo:

- Faltar o arquivo `config/master.key`, responsável por decodificar suas credenciais em ambiente de produção;

  > **Obs:** É comum esquecer de subir esse arquivo para produção, visto que não é uma boa prática envia-lo para repositórios git
- Estar faltando a definição do `secret_key_base`, ou possuir algum erro em sua especificação, pois o ambiente de desenvolvimento, dependendo de sua configuração, pode não ser tão rigoroso com a existência dessa definição.

Segue um tutorial que pode te ajudar ao longo desse processo: [Rails 5.2: Encrypted Credentials (O novo Secrets)](https://onebitcode.com/rails-5-2-credentials/)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu Problema com o Puma em produção da seguinte forma

Executar o comando  e copiar a chave gerada
    rake secret
Criar em config um arquivo chamado secrets.yml e copiar a chave gerada com o seguinte formato

production:
 secret_key_base: 7004d57f202ac9dcdeee45...

rails s Puma -b IP -e production